# Mint: add file association to application in the (desktop) menu

Tags: linux-mint, system-preferences, app-menu

It's my first attempt to customize the application menu in Cinnamon (out-of-the-box, standard Linux Mint desktop environment). I want to associate a file extension to a menu item (i.e. set a preference).

I would like to set a preference to open PostScript (*.ps) files with Ghostview (the X10 front-end / GUI for Ghostwriter). I found a suggestion on Superuser, which I tried to follow, as such:
From the desktop, I can navigate `menu-> configure -> choose the tab, "Menu" -> then, "Open the Menu Editor"`,
but, having arrived at this location, regardless of whether I choose `New Menu` or `New Item`, I cannot get either of these dialog boxes to accept my entries (i.e., I can only choose `Cancel`, never `OK`).

As I cannot get beyond this point, I cannot determine if I am even in the correct place to associate a file type (*.ps in this case) with a given application.

Comment: You might get more hits if you specify the actual desktop manager you are using and not simply "Mint".  KDE? Gnome? Mate? Cinnamon? etc etc.  An expert on desktop managers but not specifically Mint could easily answer this question but your question may not have the keywords they queue into.

Comment: You might try using PCMan FM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCMan_File_Manager), which I find makes it easier to set the *Open with* app. You can even use a command line, e.g., for an app running in wine, to specify *wine appname*, and you can name that choice. The alternative is to create a .desktop file: see https://saveriomiroddi.github.io/Linux-associating-file-types-to-applications/.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I discovered while trying to resolve this.

In Cinnamon (the out-of-the-box, standard Linux Mint desktop environment), `desktop menu--> configure --> menu --> open the menu editor` is ***not*** the correct place to make this file association. That location is where you can choose the *groupings* of your applications by their *overall functionality*, and also create additional functional groupings.

The place to make the *file association* with a *default executable* is directly from a file of the desired type (eg. my_file.ps):

1. Right-mouse-click the file in question,
2. then choose `open with --> other --> other application --> field "type or choose a custom executable..."`
3. You can then choose to make that executable the ***default*** for that file-type (*.extension), or use it only as a one-shot

The right-click-from-the-desired-file menu method is a familiar one.  It can be done this way in Windows, for example. However, while Windows has the option to perform file-opening associations from a GUI desktop-menu, the confusingly similar Linux Mint (Cinnamon) cascading menu does ***not*** (to the best of my current knowledge) have such functionality.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).